# Google App Engine Deploy Error Code 9

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

All,

I'm attempting to deploy a Google App Engine. I've gotten as far as this, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
Updating service [default]...
......failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] The App Engine service account does not exist for "[my-project]".
```

It appears that I need to create a service account for the app engine, but I'm not sure what variables it needs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that I had deleted the "App Engine default service account".

I was able to re-add the account using [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/repair).

On the right side of the page is a tool to "Try the API". For the `appsId` enter the project to be repaired and then click 'Execute'.

The tool will walk you through a series of steps and at the end repair the project.