# Vapor 3 - Error Response 9 on Fluent MySQL when deploying to GCP App Engine

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, vapor, vapor-fluent

I’m getting a weird error when trying to deploy my Vapor project onto GCP App Engine. I was able to deploy it previously but this error just began out of nowhere. I believe it has something to do with my Fluent Migrations but don’t seem to know how to pinpoint this issue… does anyone have any idea as to why my migration might suddenly fail when it worked before? I followed this tutorial to get it up on App Engine: https://medium.com/swift2go/serverless-google-app-engine-flex-docker-runtime-cloud-sql-backend-with-swift-vapor-web-alfian-c8310acfea0d

I already looked at this stackOverflow question but it is not the same as my issue: [Google App Engine Deploy Error Code 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44676231/google-app-engine-deploy-error-code-9)

[image]

Comment: There seems to be an error in the connection to your Cloud SQL database, did anything change? Can you check your SQL instance logs on GCP? Any further information about the timing of these changes might help.

Comment: super late sorry, but basically when i try connecting to a public IP Cloud SQL instance on GCP, the app deploys but when I make the connection a private IP (I have to make it private for my purpose) it gives me this error. Nothing on the SQL logs gives a clear answer :/